# Can an algorithm complexity be lower than its tight low bound / higher than its tight high bound?

Tags: data-structures

The worst case time complexity of a given algorithm is $\theta(n^3logn)$.
Is it possible that the worst time complexity is $\Omega(n^2)$?
Is it possible that the worst time complexity is $O(n^4)$?
The average time complexity is $O(n^4)$?

IMO it is possible as long as you control the constant $c$, but then what's the point of mentioning any other bound than the tight bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t(x)$ be the time taken for input $x\in \{0,1\}^*$, and $T(n)=\max_{x\in\{0,1\}^*,|x|=n}t(x)$ is the worst case.

If $T\in\theta(n^3\log(n))$, this means that there are constants $C_1,C_2$ and $N$ such that for all $n> N$ you have $$C_1n^3\log(n)\leq T(n)\leq C_2n^3\log(n)$$.

Since $n^3\log(n)\geq n^2$ for $n>1$, then $C_1n^2\leq C_1n^3\log(n)\leq T(n)$. Therefore, $T\in\Omega(n^2)$.

We also have that $n^3\log(n)\leq n^4$, for all $n>1$. Therefore, $T(n)\leq C_2n^3\log(n)\leq C_2n^4$.

This implies that $T\in O(n^4)$.

Finally, $$\begin{align}A(n)&=E(t(x), |x|=n)\\&\leq E(T(n), |x|=n)\\&=T(n)E(1,|x|=n)\\&=T(n)\\&\leq C_2n^3\log(n)\\&\leq C_2n^4\end{align}$$, for $n>1$. Therefore, the average number of steps satisfies $A\in O(n^4)$.

---

Sometimes computing tight bounds is hard, while more relaxed bounds are more accessible.

Answer (score 2):

If $T(n) = \Theta(n^3\log n)$ then it is *always* the case that $T(n) = \Omega(n^2)$ and $T(n) = O(n^4)$.

If $T(n)$ is the worst-case complexity of an algorithm, then furthermore its average-case complexity is $O(n^4)$, *always*.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the algorithm you have or the recurrence relation you have do not give you enough information other than the upper bounded relation. i.e. $T(n) \le 2T(n/2) + n$. So you can only upper bound the algorithm unless you have additional information on the lower bound as well.